# Perfmon takes up entire memory

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, memory-usage, perfmon

Is it expected?

- Windows 2008 R2 Storage Server SP1, 6GB physical RAM, 18 GB Paging file
- Running 12 hours of Perfmon collection with low sample interval
- After some time, Commit charge reaches the limit , windows screams and all sort of issues follow, caused by memory shortage.
- additionally errors "An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk2\DR2 during a paging operation."  appear in  the eventlog.
- Eventually memory is released

This does not make sense to me.Should Perfmon even be allowed to consume all memory?
Disk error message  does not make it easier to decipher either.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most definitely shouldn't but I don't think that there is a way through the UI wizard
to set maximum memory consumption.

A workaround that comes to mind is configure your perfcounters through logman and then do something like:

```
start /LOW tracerpt.exe
```